# xpath expression to find either one type of element or another

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I am trying to get either a parent li or tr from an element with specific text.

As it stands I am just trying different separate xpath expressions, but I am curious if I can just make one that goes something like this:

```
'//[tr | li]//*[contains(text(), "Some Text")]'
```

or

```
'//*[contains(text(), "Some Text")]/[ancestor::tr | ancestor::li]'
```

I have found that I can just string the statements together like so:

```
'//li[descendant::*[contains(text(), "Some Text")]] | //tr[descendant::*[contains(text(), "Some Text")]]'
```

but that isn't ideal either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following XPath is your desired expression :

```
//li[descendant::*[contains(text(), "Some Text")]] | //tr[descendant::*[contains(text(), "Some Text")]]
```

You can do :

```
(//tr|//li)[.//*[contains(text(), "Some Text")]]
```

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful.  Do you have a resource for further info about this.  I have trouble finding anything.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
//[tr | li]
```

use

```
//*[self::tr or self::li]
```